# Meteor: Accessing another collection with an id in an #each block

Tags: javascript, meteor, each

So I have two collections, appliers & profiles,

```
appliers = {_id,idAppliersProfile}
```

&

```
profile = {_id,profilename}
```

So my question is if I do an #each for appliers, how do I access profile collection to get the profile instead of just the id?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both sets of docs are published to the client, one solution looks something like this:

**html**

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{#each appliers}}
    {{#with getProfile idAppliersProfile}}
      <div>{{profilename}}</div>
    {{/with}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

**js**

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  appliers: function () {
    return appliers.find();
  },

  getProfile: function (id) {
    return profile.findOne(id);
  }
});
```